# Can I change the expected Rails version of a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I downloaded an archive containing code for a Rails application ( from a book I'm reading ). I'm running Rails `3.0.1` but the application fails to start, because it's looking for `3.0.0beta3`. Is there some way of starting it with my version of Rails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, look for the Gem file in the application root and look for the line

gem 'rails', '3.0.0beta3' and change it to 
gem 'rails', '3.0.1'

then run bundle install from a terminal in your application root.

Comment: What is the difference between "gem install XXX" and "bundle install"? Can I understand it in the way that "bundle install" install all gems needed in the app at once while "gem install XXX" only install the specified "XXX" gem ?

Answer (score 1):

this is because your Gemfile.lock is probably showing Rails 3.0.0.beta3. Even if you change your Gemfile to 3.0.1 AND install it using `gem install rails`, you will need to run `bundle install` or `bundle update rails`

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a line in the `environment.rb` file that looks like

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '3.0.0beta3' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

Updating this should sort your issue.

Comment: No, Rails 3 applications use a Gemfile to store the Rails version. The `environment.rb` does not contain a version anymore.

Comment: Ah, okay... I did a bit of a search and saw RAILS_GEM_VERSION mentioned in connection to version 3, and assumed it must still use the same scheme. My mistake.